# prevent moving button in webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a button over webview and I want to ask how to prevent from moving that button when im scrolling down along webview? Im using Relative layout
I did this, but im looking for better solution

```
   webView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            if (scrollX == 0 && scrollY == 0 ){
                myBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                myBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }

        }
    });   

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFD0">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    </WebView>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/myBtn"
        android:backgroundTint="#172632"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="Scanner"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you want one view over another view then try to use FramLayout

Comment: Add the following changes to your button
 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Comment: i can see my button I just want to prevent it from moving while im scrolling trough webview